# calculate distance of vehicular nodes for every time instance

Tags: c++, ns-3

i have to calculate distance between cars for every second in simulation my code only displays for time =0

simulator::schedule

```
double
 GetDistance_From (Ptr<Node> node1, Ptr<Node> node2)
{

  Ptr<MobilityModel> model1 = node1->GetObject<MobilityModel>();
  Ptr<MobilityModel> model2 = node2->GetObject<MobilityModel>();
  double distance = model1->GetDistanceFrom (model2);
 return distance;

}
```

and call in main function

```
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
   {
     for (int k=i+1; k < 5; k++)
       {
          double dist= GetDistance_From(c.Get(i),c.Get(k));
         // Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(10), GetDistance_From,c.Get(i),c.Get(k), dist);
         int t = (Simulator::Now ()).GetSeconds ();

        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss  << "distance between Source Node(" << i << ") and Node(" <<k<<  ") est= " << dist<<" at time="<< t ;

       NS_LOG_UNCOND (oss.str());
       }
   }
```

results are only for one time

Answer (score 0):

You have to put that code inside a loop that runs evey 1000ms to simulate time passing.

Comment: thanks fro reply but can you please elaborate your answer

Comment: Put your code inside a do...while loop, start a clock before the loop and end it when the timer reaches the time you want it to run.

Comment: @samar You don't necessarily have to duplicate the passage of time. You may be able to simply declare each iteration of the loop to be one second and finish the simulation tens of thousands to times  faster.

Comment: your answer only displays different times but calculated distances are same

Comment: That's because speed is not changing throughout the loop. Make some changes in the speed at the end of each iteration

Comment: yes  you area right actually I also want to add mobility of nodes to the function but failed

Comment: As I suggestion I would generate a random acceleration value (inside or outside the loop) so the distances will change every time a cycle ends

Answer (score 0):

Simply reorganize your code and make use of the `Simulator::Schedule()` function

```
void
 GetDistance_From (Ptr<Node> node1, Ptr<Node> node2, int i, int k)
{

  Ptr<MobilityModel> model1 = node1->GetObject<MobilityModel>();
  Ptr<MobilityModel> model2 = node2->GetObject<MobilityModel>();
  double distance = model1->GetDistanceFrom (model2);
  std::ostringstream oss;
  oss  << "distance between Source Node(" << i << ") and Node(" <<k<<  ") est= " << distance<<" at time="<< Simulator::Now().GetSeconds() ;
  NS_LOG_UNCOND (oss.str());

}
```

and inside main() -

```
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
   {
     for (int k=i+1; k < 5; k++)
       {
          double dist= GetDistance_From(c.Get(i),c.Get(k));
          Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(10), GetDistance_From,c.Get(i),c.Get(k),i,k);
       }
   }
```